# Strings in the SDK, translated in all languages?

Tags: android

Is there a list of strings included in the SDK of android?
For example, I have the strings :

- android:string/yes
- android:string/ok

Are they more ? Where can I see this list ?

Comment: i think u need to use google for that and add those manually for each language.You may wanna check https://localize-software.phraseapp.com/posts/android-how-to-translate-apps-in-android-studio/

Comment: Some default strings are there like android:string/yes and android:string/ok like that these are supported to multiple languages other wise you have to mantain multiple values folders for supporting other multiple languages like values-es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a very strings available in the default SDK. However, you can create your own string folders according to the countries required. In this For eg. if you need the strings in Norwegian format, you would create a folder with the name values_nb and create a strings xml file with all the strings present in the normal strings file but containing their translated values. The check on Locale would be handled programatically and the values would change automatically according to the country